# ASP.NET Core: jquery.validate.js is not working when used with another <script> tag

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

Using `VS2017`, I've created an ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1.1 app by using a default `ASP.NET Core Web Application` template with `Individual User Account` mode. As we know `VS2017` creates and configures all necessary `css` and `javascripts` files inside the project by default. The `validation` is working fine on both client side and server side accept when I use an javascript along with `jquery.validate.js` as shown below:

**Observations**

1. When I enter a correct value (of type float) in input box, the form submits successfully and the value gets inserted into the SQL db. But intentionally if I enter a string, say, abc the client-side error does not occur but on post action, as expected, `ModelStat.IsValid` returns false and hence the data does not get inserted into the db.
2. On the source view (shown below) of the page (or using F12), I can see the  `jquery.validate.js` is loaded correctly
3. I've tried loading  `jquery.validate.js` before `<script>...<\script>` and then moving it to after `<script>...<\script>` but `jquery.validate.js` loads successfully yet client-side validation still does not work.

**View**

```
@model MyProj.Models.MainViewModel
 ...
<div class="form-group">
 <label asp-for="Price"></label>
 <div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control"></input>
    <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div>
   <button type="submit" name="submit"...>GO</button>
 </div>

@section scripts
{  
   @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     ...
     ...
     });
   </script>
}
```

**Page Source View**

```
...
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <small class="input-group-addon">$</small>
    <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." id="Price" name="Price" value="">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Price" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
...
</div>
...
       <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
       <script src="/js/site.js?v=EWaMeWsJBYWmL2g_KkgXZQ5nPe-a3Ichp0LEgzXczKo"></script>


    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    ...
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: @section should not be rendered like that in html

Comment: @JoeAudette That was a typo in the `Page Source View` part of the post - I've corrected that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: are you getting any script errors on the page? do you have annotations for validation on your view model? you should show your view model and also your view at least partially in your question

Comment: are you saying it works as expected if you leave out the last script element? if so probably need to know more about what that script does since it seems to break it

Comment: for unobtrusive validation there should be relevant data- attributes rendering on the elements to be validated, that is how the validation gets wired up

Comment: @JoeAudette The relevant attributes are there. After reading your last comment I just added some more content to the `View` section of the post above.

Comment: no script errors? no 404s for scripts? you should show what data- attributes are rendered on the input for price

Comment: @JoeAudette Per your request I've added more content to the `rendered` page. The form is loaded via a partial view, does that make a difference? I'm asking sine reading your comments it seems to me validation should have worked per what is described in the post.

Comment: yeah code looks ok, nothing jumps out at me as wrong. partial view is ok unless it is loaded by ajax that might make it miss out on getting wired up unobtrusively. on page load the unobtrusive script should see the data- attributes and wire up the validation, but if loaded by ajax after page load that could explain the problem. if the partial view is rendered during initial page load it should work

Answer (score 2):

Its too late but hope this help you

use `unobtrusive` too like this :

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
}
```